# Mysqldump really slow when dumping to network drive

Tags: mysql, samba, mysqldump

I'm facing an issue when dumping a mysql database to the network drive. The thing is I'm getting really slow speeds (around 3-7mb/s).

Dumping locally, the speed is fine. I've coded my own program that performs automatic backups 4 times per day and dumps from main server (windows vps) to a Linux vps’s samba server. Both of the servers have 1gb/s port speed. The thing is, for example when
I manually upload a random file to the Linux machine's samba server, I get speeds up to 100mb/s. The database is around 45GB large. Also, before I was performing backups on a windows machine, had the program running there and it dumped the databases over network, speeds were also up to 100mb/s then. What could be the issue that i'm getting so slow speeds when dumping directly to the network drive?

The command I use:

```
mysqldump -u root -ppassword --single-transaction --hex-blob database worlds > "\\mysambaserver\Storage\folder\worlds.sql"
```

Comment: Were you piping?  Or writing to disk, then reading it?  Which machine was the dump program running on?  What is the network latency?

Comment: Could you please add the output of `strace -c mysqldump ... > "\\mysambaserver\Storage\folder\db.sql"` I would like to see if your writes are slow compared to reads from DB.

Comment: You could try to compress the DB on the fly: `mysqldump ... | gzip > "\\mysambaserver\share\db.sql"`